# How to create a new repo in git from the sbt file?

Tags: git, scala, sbt

I wanted to create new repo for existing one from my `build.sbt` such that I have cloned an exist repo and in the sbt file I have one field with the name of the project(contains the new updates)and another one with the programmer name, I need the sbt to create new repo with new project as it mentioned in the field of project name inside sbt ?

example :

`val projectName = "my-first-app"`
`val programmerName = "xxxxx"`

the repo looks like below:

https://github.com/github-name/ my-first-app.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little research and did not find such plugin for sbt. I suppose this is not a build system feature, since I did not see this feature when I used Maven, Gradle and MSBuild.